# Is it possible to use pyparsing for nested calls in a string?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm developing a parser for a config format that also uses functions and I'm trying to figure if it's possible to use pyparsing for this task.

My input is

```
%upper(%basename(filename)fandsomemore)f%lower(test)f _ %lower(test2)f
```

and the finite result should be

```
FILENAMEANDSOMEMOREtest _ test2
```

In order to do this I first have to get the function names and arguments. My current code works only for the upper function and the nested basename and only if the "andsomemore" part is missing. The code is bellow:

```
from pyparsing import *

identifier = Word(alphas)
integer  = Word(nums)
functor = identifier
expression = Forward()

lparen = Literal("%").suppress() + functor + Literal("(").suppress()
rparen = Literal(")f").suppress()

argnrec = identifier | integer
arg = Group(expression) | argnrec
args = arg + ZeroOrMore("," + argnrec)
expression << Group(lparen + args + rparen)

print expression.parseString("%upper(%basename(filename)f)f%lower(test)f%lower(test2)f")
print expression.parseString("%upper(%basename(filename)fandsomemore)f%lower(test)f _ %lower(test2)f")
```

This works great for the first print and outputs, as expected

```
[['upper', [['basename', 'filename']]]]
```

For the second print I have an error:

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected ")f" (at char 27), (line:1, col:28)
```

Is there any way to get this to work with pyparsing? If not, any alternative approach would be appreciated. Also, keep in mind that this must handle more complex arguments, like windows paths (the current code only works for alphas and numbers)

Later update:
The purpose for this is to be able to insert the functions anywhere in a string. Another possible usage would be:

```
 %upper(this)f is a %lower(TEST)f and m%upper(%lower(ORE)f)f
```

That will result in the end to

```
THIS is a test and mORE
```

Comment: Aren't multiple args supposed to be separated by commas? For the second test string, you will need to parse one or more expressions separated by '_'s - an easy way to define this is `delimitedList(expression, '_')`.  This works for me: `print delimitedList(expression,'_').parseString("%upper(%basename(filename)f,andsomemore)f_%lower(test)f _ %lower(test2)f")` This still omits the trailing `%lower(test2)f`, but to match that, you'll need to correct the definition of identifier to accept digits in the body of the string, try this: `identifier = Word(alphas,alphanums)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have updated the main post. These functions should be able to be used anywhere in a string, an even in paths. Of course the definition for the identifiers will be changed accordingly, but for now, even the simple cases seem to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Just having a play here, I'm not entirely sure what you want but perhaps this will help?

```
from pyparsing import *

identifier = Word(alphas+nums+'_')
integer  = Word(nums)
functor = identifier
expression = Forward()

lparen = Literal("%").suppress() + functor + Literal("(").suppress()
rparen = Literal(")f").suppress()

term = (lparen + expression + rparen) | identifier
#args = term + ZeroOrMore("," + argnrec)
expression << OneOrMore(term)

print(expression.parseString("%upper(%basename(filename)f)f%lower(test)f%lower(test2)f"))
print(expression.parseString("%upper(%basename(filename)fandsomemore)f%lower(test)f _ %lower(test2)f"))

C:\temp>python test.py
['upper', 'basename', 'filename', 'lower', 'test', 'lower', 'test2']
['upper', 'basename', 'filename', 'andsomemore', 'lower', 'test', '_', 'lower', 'test2']
```